# How to use `local` and a `Reader` monad with Scrap Your Boilerplate (SYB)?

Tags: generics, haskell, ghc

How can I use SYB (or some other Haskell generics package), to write a transformation in a `Reader` monad that uses `local` to modify the environment for subcomputations?  The types of `GenericM` and `everywhereM` (with `a -> m a`) don't seem to support the use of `local` (of type `m a -> m a`) to wrap a subcomputation.  I would like a solution that uses "standard" / "off the shelf" transformations if possible.

### A Representative Example

A (mysterious) recursive data type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable , Rank2Types , ViewPatterns #-}
import Data.Generics
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Arrow

data Exp = Var Int | Exp :@ Exp | Lam (Binder Exp)
  deriving (Eq , Show , Data , Typeable)
newtype Binder a = Binder a
  deriving (Eq , Show , Data , Typeable)
```

A recursive function that increments all the embedded `Int`s with values
larger than the number of `Binder`s that wrap them:

```
-- Increment all free variables:
-- If G |- e:B then G,A |- weaken e:B.
weaken1 :: Exp -> Exp
weaken1 = w 0
  where
  w :: Int -> Exp -> Exp
  -- Base case: use the environment ('i'):
  w i (Var j)          = wVar i j
  -- Boilerplate recursive case:
  w i (e1 :@ e2)       = w i e1 :@ w i e2
  -- Interesting recursive case: modify the environment:
  w i (Lam (Binder e)) = Lam (Binder (w (succ i) e))

wVar :: Int -> Int -> Exp
wVar i j | i <= j    = Var (succ j)
         | otherwise = Var j
```

The goal is to put the `i` parameter to `weaken1` in a `Reader` environment and use SYB to automatically handle the boilerplate recursive case for `(:@)`.

A rewrite of `weaken1`, using a `Reader` environment, but not SYB:

```
weaken2 :: Exp -> Exp
weaken2 e = runReader (w e) 0
  where
  w :: Exp -> Reader Int Exp
  w (Var j) = do
    i <- ask
    return $ wVar i j
  w (e1 :@ e2)       = (:@) <$> w e1 <*> w e2
  w (Lam (Binder e)) = Lam . Binder <$> local succ (w e)
```

The point of the example:

- the `(:@)` case is typical boilerplate recursion: `everywhereM` works here automatically.
- the `Var` case uses the environment, but does not modify it: `everywhereM` works here, by applying `mkM` to a `Exp -> Reader Int Exp` specific to the `Var` case.
- the `Lam` case modifies the environment before recursion: `everywhereM` does *not* work here (as far as I can tell).  The `Binder` type tells us where we need to use `local`, so that we might hope to apply `mkM` to a `Binder Exp -> Reader Int (Binder Exp)` specific case, but I can't figure out how.

[Here is a Gist with more examples](https://gist.github.com/ntc2/5667305), including the above code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution by creating a new SYB traversal, `everywhereMM`:

```
newtype MM m x = MM { unMM :: m x -> m x }
mkMM :: (Typeable a , Typeable b) => (m a -> m a) -> m b -> m b
mkMM t = maybe id unMM (gcast (MM t))

-- Apply a 'GenericM' everywhere, transforming the results with a
-- 'GenericMM'.
type GenericMM m = Data a => m a -> m a
everywhereMM :: Monad m => GenericMM m -> GenericM m -> GenericM m
everywhereMM mm m x = mm (m =<< gmapM (everywhereMM mm m) x)
```

The definitions of `everywhereMM` and `mkMM` are similar
to `everywhereM` and `mkM` in [`Data.Generics.Schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Generics-Schemes.html) and [`Data.Generics.Aliases`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Generics-Aliases.html);  the difference is that `everywhereMM` uses `mm`, a `GenericMM`, to transform the result.

Now we can write a `weaken3`.  The idea is to combine a standard `GenericM` for the `Var` case of
`Exp` with a new `GenericMM` that applies `local` in the `Binder` case:

```
type W = Reader Int
weaken3 :: Exp -> Exp
weaken3 e = runReader (w e) 0
  where
  w :: GenericM W
  w = everywhereMM (mkMM b) (mkM v)

  b :: W (Binder Exp) -> W (Binder Exp)
  b = local succ

  v :: Exp -> W Exp
  v (Var j) = do
    i <- ask
    return $ wVar i j
  v e = return e
```

But this solution is somewhat unsatisfying: creating the new traversal required digging deeply into the SYB library code.

Again, [here is a Gist with more examples](https://gist.github.com/ntc2/5667305), including the above code.